# Помогите разобраться с IniRead в AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Понятное дело что тут явная ошибка, но я понять так и не смог в чем именно проблема, пишет ошибку при запуске ERROR: Invalid hotkey

#NoEnv
    #SingleInstance Force 
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

```
IniRead, Button1, %A_ScriptDir%\config.ini, Key, Button1
IniRead, Button2, %A_ScriptDir%\config.ini, Key, Button2
IniRead, Button3, %A_ScriptDir%\config.ini, Key, Button3
IniRead, Button4, %A_ScriptDir%\config.ini, Key, Button4

~Button1::
Send,{Button3} 
Send,{LButton down}
while GetKeyState("Button1")
{
    ImageSearch, X, Y, 0,322, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %A_ScriptDir%\white.png
    if ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Sleep, 35
        Send,{Button1} 
        Sleep, 35
        Send,{Button2}
        Sleep, 35
        Send,{Button3}
        Sleep, 500
    }
}
KeyWait, LButton
Send,{LButton up} 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже хотел сделать подобный скрипт. Не получилось. При назначение горячих комбинаций через метки "key::" нельзя использовать переменные. 
Как вариант, можно постоянно в цикле опрашивать все нажатые клавиши:

```
while(work) {
  if GetKeyState(Button1) {
  ;....
  }
  if GetKeyState(Button2) {
  ;....
  }
}
```